# How to make a top colum in html

Tags: html

How do i make this in html, more specifically the top part of the website?

[image: Image of a website]

Comment: Its already in HTML right? View source?

Comment: We only got a screenshot of the website not the source code

Comment: To start with, you can use tables...

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use a table for doing your task.

```html
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

<table border=0 width=100% height =100% >
  <tr width="1340px" height="200px">
    <td colspan=3 align="center"> HEADER OF THE PART WEBSITE........</td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="1340px" height="500px">
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr width="1340px" height="200px">
    <td colspan=3 align="center"> FOOTER OF THE PART WEBSITE........</td>
  </tr>
  
</body>
</table>
</html>
```

2) Such as you can use `div` class to solve your problem.